# Akka configuration set paralellism level to cores

Tags: akka

We can configure parallelism level to a specific number like this:

```
my-thread-pool-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    core-pool-size-min = 2
    core-pool-size-factor = 2.0
    core-pool-size-max = 10
  }
  throughput = 100
}
```

But since, I want to use this config in multiple environments I'd like to set `core-pool-size-max=Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`. Is there a wayt to do that through the configuration?